# The best way to make eloquent collection to custom array

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

What is the best way to make `Object::all()` to `array('object_id', 'object_name')`?
I need a nice code to use eloquent collection for SELECT: `{{ Form:select('objects', $custom_array) }}`. Is a for loop the only way to do that ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are looking for `toArray()`:

```
User::all()->toArray();
```

http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json

To get an array that can be directly used with `Form::select()`, you can use the following:

```
$contacts = Contact::orderBy('name')->lists('name', 'id');
$contacts = count($contacts) > 0 ? $contacts : array();

{{ Form::select('contact', $contacts) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it makes me the structure of an array like this: `array(0 => array("id" => 1, "name" => "object1"), 1 => array("id" => 2, "name" => "object2") ...)` and i need it like this: `array(1 => "object1", 2 => "object2")` ;)

Comment: Ah ok, if you need an array that you can use with `Form::select()`, the following should work: `$contacts = Contact::orderBy('name')->lists('name', 'id');
$contacts = count($contacts) > 0 ? $contacts : array();
{{ Form::select('contact', $contacts }}`

Comment: Straight-up toArray() is probably not the best way to implement this in a live application, dumping your data structure straight to the client could result in unwanted vulnerabilities. I often use a Transformer to deal with this, some good examples are available @ https://github.com/ConnorVG/laravel-transform and on http://laracasts.com (paid subscription)

Comment: The `toArray()` method doesn't dump the data, it just converts it. No output is given to the client (unless you explicitly do so).